# Addming Redmine user fails (email already in use), but no user uses that email

Tags: active-directory, redmine, account, samba

I should note, this user had existed in the past, left, and then came back to be reactivated.

I inherited this Redmine system in the interim, so I don't know all of tis details (read: quirks)

===

When attempting to create the user `name.last@student.email.edu`, Redmine fails the user add saying `The email is already in use`.

However a search of Redmine users shows no such user, and can find no such email.

When searching in Redmine for both **MY** username and my email - both come up, so I think I'm doing the search correctly.

Redmine users are validated against an `Samba Active Directory` domain (not locally).

The user account seems to be fine in Samba Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One user can have multiple e-mail addresses, best way to resolve that situation is to either seek for that user via ruby console or with some SQL database query tool.

**Console approach:**

To activate ruby console, just on your Redmine server, navigate via terminal or cmd on windows to Redmine install folder and type **rails console**, you might need to add RAILS_ENV=production if required.

```
EmailAddress.find_by(address: "my@address.com")
```

Replace my@address.com with address you are looking for, or

That would return result like:

```
#<EmailAddress id: 3, user_id: 1, address: "my@address.com"...
```

Than in following query, you can get exact user id, by using user_id from previous query:

```
User.find_by(id:id_from_previous_query)
```

Just replace *id_from_previous_query*, with proper id, retruned in previous query.

**Database approach:**

E-mail addresses are located in email_addresses database table.

Below is sql code that you can run if you installed Redmine with MySql/MariaDb,
just replace %search% with email or part of email that you are searching for

```
select login,firstname,lastname,address from users left join email_addresses on users.id=email_addresses.user_id where email_addresses.address like '%search%'
```

I have also created feature proposal, based upon your inquiry here: https://www.redmine.org/issues/31043

Comment: It does find a `id` and `user_id`, but I can't see to find THOSE in the Redmine Administration Webtool either :D Is there a way to resolve those to a name?

Comment: Sql query already resolves it by name... Next step for console would be Userf.find_by(id : "if from previous query")...

Comment: Thanks. That did it :)